# Does a 220V AC fan emit much more EMI noise than a 24V DC fan?

Tags: ac, dc, fan, 24v

I've been discussing this with other colleagues for some time now and we can't reach a conclusion. Also searched on internet but didn't find a good article or proof that in fact a 220V AC fan will emit much more EMI than a 24V DC fan. For me this looks obvious but not sure. Does anyone know where can I find more information on this?

Comment: Fans are not typically EMI generators. The BLDC fans have a small loop area and paired windings with Caps for noise suppression, so it is fairly low slew rate commutation in terms of dI/dt

Comment: It would depend a lot on the construction of the fans.  A really well constructed 220VAC fan with shielding in all the right places could have less emissions than a horribly constructed 24VDC fan using mechanical commutation and no shielding and vice-versa.

Comment: If anything I would expect the AC fan to be less since no switching is involved in the AC fan. Of the same size and power anyways.

Comment: @vir I'm talking about good quality fans from same brand and similar power, the difference being just powered by 24V DC or 220V AC.

Comment: That's like saying whats slower A Masarati or fast e-car when neither are slow.

Comment: The best 100 W range fan for  is a BLDC 3 phase running off AC to DC, high voltage , low current. Very quiet too at 5000 CFM

Comment: Are you just curious or is there a reason you are asking? I normally would not worry about emissions from either of them, but I would bet money that the 24 V fan will be way more energy efficient (assuming it is a BLDC fan).

Comment: Please note that some modern 220 AC fans are in fact your run off the mill three phase brushless 12 V fan with a power supply. Unreasonably light weight and power efficient? Probably inverter type. Heavy and power hungry? Probably true AC induction.

Comment: @mkeith We have a machine using six AC (120mm) fans and we were discussing if we should change them or not to DC fans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most AC fans use a [shaded pole induction motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaded-pole_motor). Here's an example:-

[NMB 4715MS-22T-B50-B00 FAN AXIAL 119X38MM 220VAC 13W 0.1A](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/detail/nmb-technologies-corporation/4715MS-22T-B50-B00/2781710)

There are no switching devices in an induction motor, so EMI is only produced at the mains frequency and low odd harmonics. The magnetic field is largely contained by the stator core, but there will be some flux leakage similar to a transformer. AC current in the lead wires will also produce EMI at low multiples of the mains frequency.

Most DC fans of similar dimensions and style use a 4 or 6 pole [brushless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor) motor. Here's an example:-

[NMB 4715KL-05W-B50-E00 FAN AXIAL 119X38.4MM 24VDC 12W 0.5A](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/detail/nmb-technologies-corporation/4715KL-05W-B50-E00/2816076)

A BLDC motor is electronically commutated at the rotational speed multiplied by the number of pole pairs. At 3600 rpm the switching frequency of this fan might be 120 Hz, which is not much different from the operating frequency of the AC fan. However the switching action could produce harmonics into the MHz range, with varying frequency depending on fan loading etc. (commutation frequency is not locked to the mains frequency). At 0.5 A operating current it could potentially produce significantly more EMI than the AC fan, however the AC current is mostly confined inside the motor and control PCB, with the DC supply current being fairly smooth.

The 220 VAC fan could produce significant EMI at mains frequency and low harmonics (180 Hz, 300 Hz etc. on 60 Hz mains) which could be a problem for sensitive audio or sensor applications. However devices generally have to accept a large amount of EMI at these frequencies anyway, due to the ubiquity of mains wiring and appliances that draw high AC current.

The DC fan may produce a similar amount of magnetic EMI close up, but with more energy at higher harmonics caused by the fast switching action. Higher frequencies up to several hundred MHz could be efficiently radiated by the power wires or the tracks and components on the control PCB. Even if the total amount of EMI produced is less than the AC fan, the higher frequencies produced and varying frequency could be a bigger problem for sensitive circuitry that is receiving very low level signals.

So which fan would produce the most EMI? You can't tell purely from the voltage or the motor type. Hopefully both fans would be designed to minimize EMI at frequencies where it might be a problem, but you would have to test the individual devices to find out exactly what EMI they produced.

Answer (score 0):

Standard BLDC fans are very noisey .Sure there are no sparking brushes but there are usually 2 pushpull switching transistors chomping the power  up as the blades revolve .If you run your standard fan on a lab supply or a battery at the rated voltage and look on a scope across a 1 ohm series resistor you will see lots of AC as well as the DC average volts corresponding to the rated current .This nasty current waveform can cause problems .The fans with inbuilt PWM are moch worse when the speed is reduced .AC fans are much quieter.You speaking from experience fail mil 461 with a couple of DC fans .I use extra filtering and steer clear of the nasty unreliable PWM fans .